# json schema not working for type = number and pattern = 10 digit regular pattern

Tags: java, json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am trying to write a jsonschema that works for a phone number which is a number and it should be equal to 10 digit. To achieve this i have written a json schema as given below

```
{"title":"Schema","description":"Schema","type":"object","properties":{"phone_number":{"type":"number","pattern":"^[0-9]{10}$"}}}.
```

My request json is `{"phone_number":123481}`

Ideally my json schema should throw an exception telling me the phone_number is not 10-digit but there is no error which is being thrown. Can somebody tell me what is wrong in this code.

Comment: Pattern apply to strings, not numbers.

Comment: Try to send the number in string format {"phone_number":"123481"}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [JSON Schema validation draft spec](https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/json-schema-validation.html#string) lists `pattern` under "Validation Keywords for Strings".  Therefore, if you want to validate phone numbers, you will have to record them as `string`s, not `number`s.

In other words, your schema should be

```
{"title":"Schema","description":"Schema","type":"object","properties":{"phone_number":{"type":"string","pattern":"^[0-9]{10}$"}}}.
```

and your request JSON will have to be `{"phone_number":"123481"}`.

In certain places (particularly here in the UK), phone numbers can begin with zeroes, but the `number` type cannot store leading zeroes.  Also, there may be a difference between, for example, `123` and `0123` as a phone numbers, and you would not be able to tell the difference between these two if you used the `number` type.